# U+0151 ('odblacute') is not available in this font Times-Roman encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Tags: pdfbox

I'm trying to set some text ( classical Hungarian dummy: árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép ):

```
contentStream.showText(text);
```

method with PDFBOX 2.0.7,and i got

```
U+0151 ('odblacute') is not available in this font Times-Roman encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
```

for őűŐŰ characters with all PDType1Font types. Other accented characters are working. Can anyone help me? Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, "ő" is not available in WinAnsiEncoding. As explained in the [FAQ](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#fontencoding): to see what WinAnsiEncoding is, look at the [PDF Specification Appendix D](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). If the character is available in your chosen font (in windows, have a look with charmap.exe), then load the font like this:

```
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("c:/windows/fonts/times.ttf"));
```

see also the [EmbeddedFonts.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/EmbeddedFonts.java?view=markup&sortby=date) example in the source code download.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and tell you the result.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: What to do if character is not available in chosen font?

Comment: @Wortig then use a different font.  There is example code that can use several fonts, get `EmbeddedMultipleFonts.java` in the source code download.